# VBA Userform: Using a command button to navigate to another page in MultiPage

Tags: vba, userform, multipage

Using a command button to navigate to another page in MultiPage rather than clicking on the actual page at the top of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `Value` property of your MultiPage object.

Code example:

```
NameOfYourForm.NameOfYourMultiPageObject.Value = 1
```

***Be careful: First page is not value 1 but value 0***

```
'Select first page
NameOfYourForm.NameOfYourMultiPageObject.Value = 0
'Select second page
NameOfYourForm.NameOfYourMultiPageObject.Value = 1
'Select third page
NameOfYourForm.NameOfYourMultiPageObject.Value = 2
```

---

### Example with result

Here is an example with a simple UserForm and 4 buttons.

**Informations**:

Name of the form: MultiPageUserForm

Name of the multipage object: MultiPageExample

```
Private Sub SelectPage1_Click()
    MultiPageUserForm.MultiPageExample.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub SelectPage2_Click()
    MultiPageUserForm.MultiPageExample.Value = 1
End Sub

Private Sub SelectPage3_Click()
    MultiPageUserForm.MultiPageExample.Value = 2
End Sub

Private Sub SelectPage4_Click()
    MultiPageUserForm.MultiPageExample.Value = 3
End Sub
```

[image: VBA Multipage Selection Through Button]

Comment: Isn't the name of my multi page object just "Page1" if I haven't changed the name? It says that object doesn't exist

Comment: @Wells I believe the default name would be MultiPage1.

Comment: Lol. With the visual. That worked. You the man/woman

Comment: Glad this helped!